# XSLT Duplicating node & all child nodes & attributes with new values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, node-set

Good day ....
I am trying to duplicate nodes with updated/new element text and/or attribute values.

My input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products author="Jesper">
  <product id="p1">
    <name>Delta</name>
    <price>800</price>
    <stock>4</stock>
    <country>Denmark</country>
  </product>
</products>
```

The desired XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products author="Jesper">
  <product id="p1">
    <name>Delta</name>
    <price>800</price>
    <stock>4</stock>
    <country>Denmark</country>
  </product>
  <product id="NEW_p1">
    <name>NEW_Delta</name>
    <price>NEW_800</price>
    <stock>NEW_4</stock>
    <country>NEW_Denmark</country>
  </product>
</products>
```

After some time, the XSLT that I currently have is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match ="product">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <product>
      <xsl:attribute name ="id">
        <xsl:value-of select ="concat('NEW_',@id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </product>
  </xsl:template>
```

However, using the above transform, I get the following XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products author="Jesper">
  <product id="p1">
    <name>Delta</name>
    <price>800</price>
    <stock>4</stock>
    <country>Denmark</country>
  </product>
  <product id="NEW_p1"><product>
    <name>Delta</name>
    <price>800</price>
    <stock>4</stock>
    <country>Denmark</country>
  </product></product>
</products>
```

As you can see, the *product* element is added whilst I declared a new *product* element with new @id value.  Since I use  to process child nodes I believe this processes the *product* element again.

Also, I need help in updating the child node's values (prepending 'NEW_' to each value).  Searching the vast questions on this site, I believe I need a template like so:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name ="{local-name()}">
    <!--for all attributes-->
    <xsl:copy-of select ="@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/ideas with my issue.

**UPDATED**
Thank you @Mathias for your answer to my initial question.  The answer provided brought one more question involving recursion to deeper levels of an XML structure.

Input XML file:

```
    <products author="Jesper">
      <product id="p1">
        <name>Delta
          <innerName>MiddleDelta
            <baseName>FinalDelta</baseName>
          </innerName>
        </name>
        <price>800</price>
        <stock>4</stock>
        <country>Denmark
          <city>Copenhagen</city>
        </country>
      </product>
    </products>
```

And the Updated desire output file is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products author="Jesper">
  <product id="p1">
    <name>Delta
      <innerName>MiddleDelta
        <baseName>FinalDelta</baseName>
      </innerName>
    </name>
    <price>800</price>
    <stock>4</stock>
    <country>Denmark
      <city>Copenhagen</city>
    </country>
  </product>
  <product id="NEW_p1">
    <name>NEW_Delta
      <innerName>NEW_MiddleDelta
        <baseName>NEW_FinalDelta</baseName>
      </innerName>
    </name>
    <price>NEW_800</price>
    <stock>NEW_4</stock>
    <country>NEW_Denmark
      <city>NEW_Copenhagen</city>
    </country>
  </product>
</products>
```

I can only guess that using templates would work as seeing each node has varying level child nodes.  Thank you in advance for ideas/suggestions in this.

Comment: Did you get an answer for the deeper recursion?

Comment: @DanielHaley No I have not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in response to your updated question (which IMHO should have been asked as a new question):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="product"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- modified identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('NEW_', .)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('NEW_', .)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'd also add a priority to the template that matches `text()` so you don't get possible ambiguous template match warnings (with the template that matches `node()`).

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks. You are right to point out the problem. I have chosen a slightly different solution, though.

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k.  
One thing I am getting, after each closing tag </...> I have the text **NEW_** 
So for the updated input file above, I have 
    ...</name>NEW_  
 ...</country>NEW_

Comment: Does your stylesheet have `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` at the top level?

Comment: @michael.hor257k no it didn't.  Works great - Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You are not far off, but there are two main problems:

- you use `xsl:copy` inside the second, literal `product` element, which results in an extra `product` element in the output
- you need a way to find all child elements of a `product` element, output them again and prepend "NEW_" to their text content.

Are you sure that the `version` attribute should be set to "2.0"? Also, I am not sure what the *point* of this exercise is...

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="product">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <product id="{concat('NEW_',@id)}">
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('NEW_',.)"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </product>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products author="Jesper">
  <product id="p1">
      <name>Delta</name>
      <price>800</price>
      <stock>4</stock>
      <country>Denmark</country>
  </product>
   <product id="NEW_p1">
      <name>NEW_Delta</name>
      <price>NEW_800</price>
      <stock>NEW_4</stock>
      <country>NEW_Denmark</country>
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I learned that using templates was the way to go when transforming XML - I see use of the for-each syntax.

Comment: @Lorentz Both `for-each` and templates have their place - the important thing is that you do not use one when the other would be better. And it's true that `xsl:for-each` is a heavily-misused construct, mostly by beginners. Please do not forget to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Duly noted on the use of 'for-each' - I will keep your comments in mind as I move forward.  This exercise is part of a bigger project - I just needed to get to the heart of duplicating nodes with new data. 

Will this transform allow for recursion to deeper levels in the XML input file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lorentz No, currently, it will not. In general, people on Stackoverflow can only work with the XML shown to them. You would need to _show_ those deep structures and _explain_ in what way you would like your code to behave recursively.